# Carregar página via load com problema

Tags: php, jquery

Quero carregar uma página dentro de uma div via load passando uma variável que definirá o conteúdo da página a ser carregada.

Meu código:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carrega').click(function(){
            $('#aqui').load('pagina.php?variavel='+$('.carrega').val());
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
$arr = array('azul', 'branco', 'cinza');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $temp=$arr[$i];
    echo "<button class='carrega' value='$temp'>$temp</button>";
}
?>
<div id="aqui"></div>
</html>
```

pagina.php

```
<?php
$variavel=$_GET['variavel'];
echo $variavel;

?>
```

A página carrega corretamente, porém somente a primeira variável é passada pela URL. Não sei o que estou fazendo errado, alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim.

Quando você coloca

`$('.carrega').val()` no parâmetro ele vai pegar o primeiro elemento que contém essa classe. No seu caso sempre vai ser **azul.**

Coloque `$(this).val()`, que ele vai pegar o que você está clicando.

Comment: Muito Obrigada!!!